# Get Error Argument(s) are different! Wanted with Mockito Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I've got some problems with my unit testing. I want to do some unit testing with my code, but I found an error like this. I've looked for a solution on stack overflow, but haven't gotten the solution.

```
view.setDetailLeague(
    []
);
-> at com.example.submission3kotlin.TestAnother.getAnotherTest(TestAnother.kt:44)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
view.setDetailLeague(
    [League(dateFirstEvent=2000-08-18, idCup=0, idLeague=4328, idSoccerXML=1, intFormedYear=1992, strBadge=https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/league/badge/i6o0kh1549879062.png, strBanner=https://www.thesportsdb.com/images/media/league/banner/4m3g4s1520767740.jpg, strComplete=yes, strCountry=England, strDescriptionCN=英格兰足球超级联赛（英语：Premier League），简称英超，過往冠名為巴克萊超級聯賽（Barclays Premier League）]
);
```

and this is my presenter

```
class DetailLeaguePresenter(val view: DetailLeagueContract.View, private val scheduler: SchedulerProvider): DetailLeagueContract.Presenter {
    override fun getDetailLeague(id: String) {
        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.getClient()
            .create(UserService::class.java)
        CompositeDisposable().add(
            retrofit.responseDetailLeague(id)
                .observeOn(scheduler.ui())
                .subscribeOn(scheduler.io())
                .subscribe(
                    {
                        view.setDetailLeague(it.leagues)
                    }, { error -> Log.e("Error", error.message) }
                )
        )
    }
}
```

My test code with mockito :

```
class TestAnother {
    @Mock
    lateinit var view: DetailLeagueContract.View

    @Mock
    private val retrofitClient = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(UserService::class.java)

    @Mock
    lateinit var scheduler: SchedulerProvider

    private lateinit var mPresenter: DetailLeaguePresenter

    @Before
    fun setupEnv(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        scheduler = TestSchedulerProvider()
        mPresenter = DetailLeaguePresenter(view, scheduler)
    }

    @Test
    fun getAnotherTest(){
        val data: MutableList<League> = mutableListOf()
        val response = DetailLeague(data)
        val id = "4328"
        `when`(retrofitClient.responseDetailLeague(id)).thenReturn(Observable.just(response))

        mPresenter.getDetailLeague(id)
        verify(view).setDetailLeague(response.leagues)
    }
}
```

can anyone help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it me, or this line here `RetrofitClient.getClient().create(UserService::class.java)` doesn't actually mock the retrofit client and you are calling the network anyway?

Comment: @Fred oh yeah thank you, actually i'm forgot about that